# Extract a list of string from odata RawValues

Tags: c#, string

I have tried to figure this out for a bit but I keep coming up with very ugly code, here is what I am trying to do.

Say I have this string

```
Orders($expand=OrderDetails($expand=Product))
```

or

```
Orders($select=OrderDetails($select=Product))
```

how can build a function in C# that can return a list of string like so

```
"Orders","Orders.OrderDetails", "Orders.OrderDetails.Product"
```

Just not sure how to do this without using a whole bunch of substrings etc. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what other variations could you have in the string? can you post the code you have tried

Comment: The only other variation would be instead of $expand it would be $select

Comment: can you add that to your post as well and what would select do as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
var str = "Orders($expand=OrderDetails($expand=Product))";
var str2 = str
    .Replace("($expand=", ".")
    .Replace("($select=", ".")
    .Replace(")", "");

var list = new List<string>();
var currentStr = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in str2.Split('.'))
{
    currentStr.Append(currentStr.Length == 0 ? item : $".{item}");
    list.Add(currentStr.ToString());
}
```